# how to use dataframe.iat with string column index

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read and update my data cells values based on dataframe.iat[row, column].

my data is about 338 000 row so that I need to use the faster way (iat) for this goal.

I have to use column by its name because it changes dynamically by another loop

when I execute my code I obtain the following error

```
for i in range(30000):
    b = data_jeux.iat[i, 'skill_id_%s' % k]


ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers
```

ps: I already use df.get_value() it work correctly but I need obligatory to get a solution with .iat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [`pd.Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

With Pandas, you should generally avoid Python-level `for` loops. However, assuming you *must* iterate explicitly you can use `get_loc` to extract the column index:

```
col_loc = data_jeux.columns.get_loc
for i in range(30000):
    b = data_jeux.iat[i, col_loc(f'skill_id_{k}')]
```

Given you have a large loop, assigning `data_jeux.columns.get_loc` to a variable outside your loop and using f-strings may offer some marginal performance improvements.